# How to stack tensors without using tf.stack?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensor

Is there any way to merge Tensors in Tensorflow?
For example:
I have 128 Tensor shape all are **(40, 10)**, Now, I want merge them to shape(128, 40, 10).
I can't use *`*tf.stack([Tensor1, Tensor2, Tensor3, ...])*`* directly.

So, Is there any function that can help achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Use `tf.expand_dims` with `tf.concat`:

```
import tensorflow as tf

x1 = tf.expand_dims(tf.random.normal((40, 10)), axis=0)
x2 = tf.expand_dims(tf.random.normal((40, 10)), axis=0)
x3 = tf.expand_dims(tf.random.normal((40, 10)), axis=0)
x4 = tf.expand_dims(tf.random.normal((40, 10)), axis=0)

x = tf.concat([x1, x2, x3, x4], axis=0)
print(x.shape)
# (4, 40, 10)
```

Answer (score 0):

I saw there is a correct answers but me also provide another way by it layer(s) that I use for my working cases:

```
X = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate(axis=1)([group_1_ShoryuKen_Left, group_1_ShoryuKen_Right])
```

[Working with multiple sequences](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q62N1.png)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, my question is solved, but thanks for giving another way of thinking